# I found EL&U material on external websites? Should I do anything about it?

Tags: discussion

I found a website that reproduces EL&U questions and answers without crediting the source. For instance [this question](http://www.nxhlh.com/what-s-the-name-of-this-literary-device/) is [this one on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275315/whats-the-name-of-this-literary-device), and [this one](http://www.nxhlh.com/what-is-the-name-for-a-torture-device-that-uses-electricity-to-make-the-victim-suffer/) is [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226540/what-is-the-name-for-a-torture-device-that-uses-electricity-to-make-the-victim-s/226651#226651). I think the external website has questions from other SE communities too.

What is going on? Should I notify anyone?

Comment: @Terah, the link is right at the top.